# form submit onclick function on a td with php variables being echoed

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, html-table, form-submit

I have a table within a form, and i want to make it so that every individual cell is an input with 2 php variables as values. And when i click the cell, the form with the correct values get submitted.

```
'<TD class="hand" width="65" BGCOLOR="' . $linecolor . '" title="Book item" >'.$artIterDate .' '.$art['artnr'] .'</TD>
```

This, prints the correct information in each cell,

So I'm thinking that something like this should work if i add some sort of onclick function somewhere

```
'<TD class="hand" width="65" BGCOLOR="' . $linecolor . '" title="Book item" ><input name="book" value="'.$artIterDate .' '.$art['artnr'] ."></input>'</TD>
```

**EDIT**
Here is the `<form>` code:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" target="_blank">
```

But i can't figure out where i should put it, maybe i just don't understand how it works

Help is appreciated!

Regards,

Johan

Comment: I suppose you can add it both in <td> and <input>. Anyway, there should be no closing tag for <input>.

Comment: You want to use submit button inside <td> ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
     $('td').on('click', function(){
         var a = $(this).html();

         var b = a.split(" ");

       $.post('url.php',
       {
        a1 : b[0],
        a2 : b[1]
       },
       function(data)
       {
           //do something
       });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Hmm, what i want to do is, when i click the cell, it will submit the form to the page add.php,

Your fiddle seems to create 2 cells from text, or am i missing something?

Comment: now is that correct? According to your problem, when it clicks, the text splits into two and then sends it to php file and you can process the values and get the response.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your form.

```
<form id="myForm" action="add.php" method="post" target="_blank">
```

Then add an onclick event to each input button.

```
<input onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit()" name="book" value="'.$artIterDate .' '.$art['artnr'] .">
```